# Como mostrar generar un buscador en el componente v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Estoy realizando un data table donde muestro algunos datos de los presentadores y además de las diferentes especialidades de un expositor pero al querer buscar por alguna especialidad con el buscador no tengo ningún resultado. Estos son algunos datos que tengo guardados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo:

```
<template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              Presentadores
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="search"
                append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                label="Search"
                single-line
                hide-details
              ></v-text-field>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="listPresenters"
              :search="search"
            ></v-data-table>
          </v-card>
        </template>
    <script>
      export default {
        data () {
          return {
           listPresenter:[],
            headers: [
        { text: 'NOMBRE', value: 'presenter.presenter_name' },
        { text: 'APELLIDO', value: 'presenter.presenter_surname' },
        { text: 'EMAIL', value: 'presenter.presenter_email' },
        { text: 'TELÉFONO', value: 'presenter.presenter_phone' },
        { text: 'ESPECILIDAD', value: 'speciality' },
        { text: 'CURRÍCULUM', value: 'cv' ,sortable: false },
        { text: 'ESTADO', value: 'actions' },
        { text: 'ACCIONES', value: 'action',sortable: false },
      ],
            search: '',
          }
        },
      },
    mounted(){
      this.getPresenter()
      
    },    methods:{
    getPresenter(){
        axios.get('/*...*/')
        .then((result) => {
            this.listPresenter=result.data
            console.log(result.data)
        })
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Como puedo hacer para que el buscador me obtengo todos los datos por especialidades?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el script js?

Comment: ¿ Que parte del codigo exactamente?

Comment: Donde podamos ver listPresenters, headers,  el código javascript, https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#custom-filter

Comment: Te puede ayudar esta esta entrada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52845201/local-search-v-data-table-vuetify